# Using classes to overlap tkinter frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, frame

I am trying to understand why Home is not defined. I am trying to create a simple GUI applications which switch to the next frame within the main Tkinter frame. Each button should move to the next page (class). I am starting of with a foundation so i can copy it each way through. Here is my error:

> builtins.AttributeError: type object 'Home' has no attribute 'tk'

```
from tkinter import *

class mainframe(Frame): 
    def raise_frame(rootFrame):
        rootFrame.tkraise

        Home = Frame(root)
        pageOne = Frame(root)
        pageTwo = Frame(root)

        for rootFrame in (Home, pageOne, pageTwo):
            rootFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

class Home(Frame):           
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.startIntro()

    def startIntro(self):
        self.introLabel = Label(self.root, text=" Welcome!", anchor=CENTER, background="white").pack()
        self.introButton = Button(self.root, text='Go to Page 1', command= lambda:raise_frame(pageOne)).pack()

class pageOne(Frame):
    def firstFrame(self):
        self.firstLabel = Label(self.root, text='Page 1').pack()
        self.firstButton = Button(self.root, text='Go to Page 2', command= lambda:raise_frame(pageTwo)).pack()

class pageTwo(Frame):
    def secondFrame(self):
        self.secondLabel = Label(self.root, text='Page 2').pack()
        self.secondButton = Button(self.root, text='Return to Home', command= lambda:raise_frame(Home)).pack()


def main():
    root=Tk()
    root.geometry('600x600')
    mainframe(Home)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There are couple problems here. Following two can lead you in the right direction. You are using the name `Home` more than one thing which confuses interpreter and you. Another thing is you are not calling tkraise. `rootFrame.tkraise`

Comment: I apologise, but i am still struggling to understand. When creating the code as a beginners pov it looks like i have declared the home as root, but also raise_frame in my command.

Comment: You have `Home` as a class, and also as an instance of another class.

Comment: I now understand thank you for your clarity